# Connecting to a sharepoint via vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm not finding much on google regarding this, using the Microsoft.SharePoint to connect to a SharePoint.

What I'm looking for is to simply query the sharepoint and iterate through every item on it, checking the file size of each item, and noting if the item exceeds a threshold.

Is there any way to do this other than loading the sharepoint in a WebBrowser object and screen scraping?

Does anyone have a link to this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not working with VB.net, but in C# code can be like this.

```
class SharePointOperation : IDisposable
{
    private ClientContext oContext;
    private Web oWeb;

    public SharePointOperation(string webUrl)
    {
        oContext = new ClientContext(webUrl);
        oWeb = oContext.Web;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get list items
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="listName"></param>
    /// <param name="camlQuery"></param>
    /// <param name="callback"></param>
    public void GetListItems(string listName, string camlQuery, Action<ListItemCollection> callback)
    {
        ListItemCollectionPosition position = new ListItemCollectionPosition {PagingInfo = ""};
        ListItemCollection oItems;
        List oList = oWeb.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);

        do
        {
            CamlQuery oQuery = new CamlQuery { ViewXml = camlQuery };
            oQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition = position;

            oItems = oList.GetItems(oQuery);
            oContext.Load(oItems);
            oContext.ExecuteQuery();
            callback(oItems);
            position = oItems.ListItemCollectionPosition;
        } while (position != null);



    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        oContext.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I have created a class SharePoint operations to work with. To get the data from a list, I can do like this.

```
   string caml = "<View><RowLimit>10</RowLimit><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='Text'>Title value</Value></Eq></Where>/Query></View>";

 using (SharePointOperation op = new SharePointOperation("https://url"))
{
                op.GetListItems("List name",caml, (ListItemCollection items) =>
                {
                   // Code not extended for  brevity
                    MessageBox.Show("Done");
                });
}
```

The last parameter is an action which executed each time you get the data. Data is retrieved in chunks to avoid problems working with a large number of items. Anyhow, this only one idea. You can convert C# to VB.net and should work for you.

To work with SharePoint data from external application, do not forget to add references to client object model libraries. These can be typically found at C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI. Just add reference to Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll and Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll

using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;